# When an operator on $L^2(X,\mu)$ becomes compact operator? ($X$ is compact)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Here is the setting.

$X$ is a compact complete separable metric space.

$\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $X$.

Then, when a linear operator $A$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$ becomes compact operator?
is there some well known criteria for that?

Comment: this may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space

Comment: If $A$ has an $L^2$-integrable kernel, then it is compact (even Hilbert-Schmidt), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator).